# align "Show 10 entries" in datatable to right instead of left

Tags: jquery, html, datatable, datatables

How can i align "Show 10 entries" option from left to right in datatable jquery?

I tried the below but did not helped

```css
div.dataTables_length label {
 font-weight: normal;
text-align: right;
 white-space: nowrap;
 align:center;
}
```

Comment: can you show an example of the <div> with the 10 entries?.. maybe i'll understand better and be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Datatable DOM positioning options something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "dom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">'
    } );
} );
```

Here `r,t,f,l,p` are

```
l - Length changing
f - Filtering input
t - The Table!
i - Information
p - Pagination
r - pRocessing
```

You can change these values as per your need.

More explanation [here](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the CSS I use to align the Length, Paginate, Filter, and Info components for datatables.

```
.dataTables_paginate {
    float: left;
}
.dataTables_filter {
    float: left;
}
.dataTables_length {
    float: right;
}
.dataTables_info {
    float:right;
}
```